# SCRIPT5007: Unable to set property 'onclick' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, iframe

This is the Page structure that I'm using now

[image: Page Structure]

Simply trying to call the function, on the click of Iframe content window while document get ready.

On document ready I'm getting the script error, couldn't understand whats the reason. I tried to put the code on **window.onload** but *still I have same issue*. Can anyone guide me on the script error? what can be the reason or where I went wrong?

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    document.getElementById("homeFrame").contentWindow.document.body.onclick = function() 
    {
      hideEmpDiv();
    }
});
```

Browser : IE10

Comment: Maybe you need domready of frame document...

Comment: Are you sure you haven't run some cached code when you've tried `window.onload`? It should work.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. It doesn't work on window.onload

Comment: This is confusing, `body` can be found even from `about:blank`. Except if the document in `iframe` is not in the same domain. Anyway, we need a _reproduceable_ example to play with, a link to the page perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Try this but i'll doubt you'll need the document ready function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    window.onload = function () {       
      document.getElementById("homeFrame").contentWindow.document.body.onclick = function() 
         {
             hideEmpDiv();
         }
      if (Element == null) return false;
    }
});
```